# Https not working in Internet explorer 11

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am running a web application in Apache Tomcat 7 using https it is working good in chrome but when I tried to run it in Internet explorer using https it is not working and it says "This page can't be displayed"
Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/964411/website-works-in-chrome-but-not-in-internet-explorer may help you.

Comment: Are u using a self-signed certificate?